# Adding data in Summary Information of Robot Framework report.html

Tags: python, robotframework

I am using robot framework integrated with python to perform automation, after the execution we get a section of **"Summary Information"** in the test report where we get the data like **start time** , **end time** etc. So i wanted to add some more information in that section but unfortunately i am not able to get any tag through which it can be added. Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 1):

In the test case file under Settings Section, you can update the documentation as below:

```
  *** Settings ***
Documentation     This file has test cases related to Authentication
Library           SeleniumLibrary
```

In the report, you can see documentation listed in Summary Information in the below screenshot

[image: Report]

Comment: Thanks but when i am running it with command "`call([exe, '-m', 'robot', robot_filepath])`" in order to run a robot script through python its working , and if i simply run my robot file through eclipse IDE then i am not getting metadata in summary section... @Rakesh can you plz help me

Answer (score 1):

That is done with the [so-called metadata](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#free-test-suite-metadata), which then appears in the report.html & log.html files.
There are (at least) two ways to add it - in the Settings section:

```
Metadata    My Info        metadata text: *formatting* is _supported_ close to ``markdown``
```

, and as a command line argument:

```
--meta from:command_line
```

It then appears in both - the report.html:

[image: the report.html file]

, and log.html:

[image: log.html]

Comment: Thanks but when i am running it with command "call([exe, '-m', 'robot', robot_filepath])" in order to run a robot script through python its working , and if i simply run my robot file through eclipse IDE then i am not getting metadata in summary section